# SSH session held open when running a forked script

Tags: python, linux, ssh, tunnel

I have a parent script (start.py) who's primary purpose is to start background processes and exit. When I ssh directly to remote_host and run the script, it works as expected.

```
[user@local_host ~]# ssh remote_host
user@remote_host's password: ****
[user@remote_host ~]# time python start.py --config_file /data/workload.pg
real    0m0.037s
user    0m0.025s
sys     0m0.012s
```

The exit code of this script:

```
[root@perf72 ~]# echo $?
0
```

To simplify, instead of establishing the ssh session first and running the command, I want to just execute the command remotely from local_host:

```
[user@local_host ~]# ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i /tmp/tmpqcz5l5il user@remote_host -p 22 "python start.py --config_file /data/workload.pg"
real   12m6.594s
user    0m0.027s
sys     0m0.016s
```

The problem here is that the ssh session remains open during the life of the background processes and not the life of the start.py script which is less than one second. It should just disconnect when the start.py script exits, but it doesn't.

Do I need a specific sys.exit() signal in the start.py script which will prompt the ssh session to disconnect?

Comment: Please properly format code using backticks or spaces to highlight the  codes and commands

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ssh is awaiting output on the called process's `stdout`, so it can print it if there is any. That file handle is inherited by the subprocesses you're spawning, so it's still open even though the python script has exited, and as long as it's open, ssh will keep waiting.

If you change your ssh command line to run the remote script as `"python start.py --config_file /data/workload.pg > /dev/null"` instead, the ssh connection will close as soon as the python script does.